# Rails: How to add text to the first value in the "each" roop if the value exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My view image as below.

What I'd like to do is to display `Total:` in the first line.

```
Total: USD 12.34
       EUR 23.45
       GBP 34.56
```

The number of data may change whether data exist or not.

```
Total: AUD 45.67
```

Nothing is displayed if there is no data.

Although I tried `each_with_index`, it doesn't work when there is no `currency` and `amount`.

**sample data**

```
room_id | event_id | currency | amount |
  1     |     3    |          |        |
  2     |     4    |    1     |  12.34 |
```

**view**

```
...
<% room.amounts.group(:currency).sum(:amount).each_with_index do |(currency, amount), index| %>

  <% if index == 0 %>
     Total
  <% end %>

  <% if currency.present? && amount.present? && amount > 0 %>
    <div align="right">

      <% if currency == 1 %>
       USD
      <% elsif currency == 2 %>
       EUR
      <% elsif currency == 3 %>
       GBP
      ...
      <% end %>

      &nbsp;

      <%= number_to_currency(amount, :format => "%n", :precision => 2) %>

    </div>

  <% end %>

<% end %>
...
```

**schema**

```
create_table "amounts", force: :cascade do |t|

  t.integer  "room_id"
  t.integer  "event_id"
  t.integer  "currency"
  t.decimal  "amount"
  ...
```

Although I have tried some codes, I couldn't come up with a solution.

It would be appreciated if you could give me how to realize what I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is not very clean code. You have to much going in the view. But if you use each_with_index it will give you index in the loop and you want index == 0 to display Total

so here:

```
room.amounts.group(:currency).sum(:amount).each_with_index do |currency, amount, index|
```

later...

```
<% if index == 0 %>
  Total
<% end %>
```

That is the quick way of doing it.

EDIT

so it seems that there is this line which you want to include in as well

```
<% if currency.present? && amount.present? && amount > 0 %>
```

You can add this before this line

```
room.amounts.group(:currency).sum(:amount)

<% total_added = false %>
room.amounts.group(:currency).sum(:amount)
```

later after this line

```
<% if currency.present? && amount.present? && amount > 0 %>
..
<% if total_added == false %>
  Total:
  <% total_added = true %>
<% end %>
```

So you would check if the total is added and once you do it you set to true so it does not add again

In my opinion view should not make any complex condition and rendering...there are decorators (presents) and helper that can help clean and refactor this. But it should at least work for a start.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, @Mirza Memic. It doesn't work if there is no `currency` and `amount` in the first line, and there is data in the second line. I added the sample data at the beginning of my question.

Comment: If no currency do you still display this line?

Comment: Yes, `Total` is displayed @Mirza Memic. I edited my view.